# Xamarin widget button, NameResolutionFailure HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So I am facing what I think is a strange problem.

I have made a small xamarin app that uses a widget button to POST to a server using HttpWebRequest. Everything works just fine when I use my phone in debug mode trough VS.

But when I disconnect my phone and try to use the app I get the NameResolutionFailure.

It is not an DNS issue as it is Tesla motors servers, and it works when debugging.

As for permissions I have set internet and access network state.

Anyone know where my problem might be? Is there any other permission sets that needs to be included?

Any help will be appriciated as I have come to a loss with this one..

This is where the code gets the NameResolutionFailure error, but not sure if it is related to other problems in settings etc. This only happens from the widget button click, not if i add a button  in the app itself..

```
        private static string postToInterface(string methodPosting, string linkExtension, string token = null, string JSON = null)
    {
        try
        {
            //Create the web socket
            HttpWebRequest webSocket = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/" + linkExtension);
            if (token != null)
            {
                webSocket.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            }

            webSocket.ContentType = "application/json";
            webSocket.Method = "POST";

            if (JSON != null)
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webSocket.GetRequestStream()))
                {

                    streamWriter.Write(JSON);
                }
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webSocket.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException error)
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)error.Response;
            return "Error: failed to post to interface. " + response.StatusCode;
        }
    }
```

changed to HttpClient:

```
        public static async Task<string> postToInterfaceNew(string linkExtension, string token = null, string JSON = null)
    {
        var body = new JObject();
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {

        };

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token); 


            using (var content = new StringContent(body.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            {
                HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress + linkExtension, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

                string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                return resultContent;
            }
        }
    }
```

Widget button:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsiQo.jpg)

App button:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzXAb.jpg)

I added an example that reproduces the issue at git:

https://github.com/salvesen/widgetSample

Examples from the widgetSample where it falls on widget button but not app button:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsiQo.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzXAb.jpg)

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Comment: @Jason added the code that faults out, but I am not sure if it will tell the story as it will work with a regular button in the app itself but faults out with the widget button. So it is totally weird and I think it is a permission/setting issue and not code related. I am fairly new to xamarin so I dont know much about settings and permissions

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` has been deprecated by Microsoft.  Have you tried using `HttpClient` instead?

Comment: Also In the project properties, in Android options, click on advanced and check what is your HttpClient implementation. In my experience the Android one works best. The old Legacy or Managed implementation have problem with DNS. You may have to reimplement the code with HttpClient as @Jason suggests.

Comment: Thanks! So I quicly changed my method to include HttpClient instead, no change unfortunatly. I also checked the android options and I use Android.

The weird thing is that when I use a  button on a page in the app this works fine 10 out of 10 times. No errors. But when I use the widget button it fails as long as I am not in debug mode. There has to be some related setting or something that is missing from the widget.

Comment: What is a "widget button"? How is it different from "a button on a page"? Sounds like that is an essential part of the problem, so include whatever information you have on it: source code? link to nuget?

Comment: I added pictures for my buttons so it makes more sense.

Comment: As a workaround I made the widget click function "click" the app button programatically calling the button_click function, but this results in the same error. So there is definitly something related to widgets or the android project that is causing the Nameresolution issues. Anyone run into this before? How can I resolve this

Comment: Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via GitHub repo?

Comment: I added an example to git, link is in original post. It is a little more stable but I am able to reproduce the nameresolutionfailure using the widget and not the button in app.

Comment: Any ideas? I am at a loss

Comment: Any help out there? I also reported this as a bug on the xamarin.forms git page

Comment: Anyone.........?